# Is there a way round the video call block on shoretel when within Xenapp

Tags: video-conversion, citrix

Is there a way round the video call block on shoretel when within Xenapp

As far as I know, there is no way to make a video chat session on ShoreTel when I am within Citrix. I can make the video chat session when on a local desktop, but the feature is blocked within XenApp. When I contact ShoreTel, they are adamant that there is no way around this, but I am sure that there is.

I would be grateful for any help, and I don’t have an issue if there is a regedit solution available.

Please note I have done a lot of reaserch into this, and have found nothing even related.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the operating-systems for host and guest?

Comment: Local is win7 and server is running win7 as well.

Comment: Could you please comment on the relevant parts in [this article](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Vdl7e2zTh6AJ:http://thecitrixman.com/%2Bvideo+%28chat+|+conference%29+ShoreTel+%28Citrix+|+xenapp%29&num=30&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=TF2&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=rcs&hl=en&&ct=clnk) from the google cache?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, none of the sections on the linked site are relevent to my problem, they disscus how to change setting in XenApp for shoretel

Comment: I thought that XenApp for shoretel was the question?

Comment: yes, but its a specific issue i am having, with the video chat

Comment: Do you mean that only video chat doesn't work? What other functions do work?

Comment: its not realy a problem, as shoretel video chat is designed not to work in XenApp, and i am looking for a way to get around this

Comment: if you go to the shoretel website, they state "video chat is not supported in XenApp"

Comment: Could you add a link to the Shoretel website where it says that? I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: here http://75-146-90-152-utah.hfc.comcastbusiness.net/jaren/ShoreTel%20documents/shoretel_12.0_release_notes.pdf

Comment: Unfortunatly it is a PDF like most of their documentaion, so needs to download

Comment: ^^ realise that looks dodgy so heres what i typed into google to find https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=video+chat+not+supported+in+XenApp+shoretel&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-gb:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&gfe_rd=cr&ei=1q-2U9-HHe_X8geTtIC4DA&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: I'm not so sure that the problem is with XenApp as with the lack of some installed software or registry keys on the client. You could do the following tests : (1) Install ShoreTel on the server and see that it works, (2) Install ShoreTel on the client and see that it works, (3) Try launching ShoreTel on same client but from XenApp, (4) If it works this time then uninstall ShoreTel on the client and try again from XenApp. The results of these tests may give us the answer, so please include them in your post with some detail. Not having your environment, I cannot test this myself.

Comment: I have tested on every device, on both local and citrix, as well as directaly from our servers (I work for a large company, and this is a whole firm issue) and have not been able to get a result.  When i contact Shoretel they inform me that they will not help me and that htere is no way to make this work

Comment: I even created a whole testing enviroment on a server with a few dumb terminals connected to see if i could access that way, but to no avail

Comment: If you have already effected these tests, what are the results for steps (3) and (4)?

Comment: I have tryed both, with no effect, allthough if i run shoretel from the local machine (as stated in the question) it works fine, as expected.

Comment: unfortunatly i have to leave now, and may not be back till monday so dont expect a responce for a while